# Replace LED by a Trasmitter

Tags: switches, transmitter

I need a wireless switch with capability to report current state, so I would like to modify a [wireless switche like this](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/RF-Wireless-fixed-code-1-Channel-Receiver-Momentary-Switch-2-Remote-controller/1687197766.html), by replacing a current state LED by a trasmitter to get the state of current wirelessly.

it is possible to make such hack? what kind of transmitter could be used ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think enough information is provided for your specific use-case to give a comprehensive or definitive answer. I would be inclined to say yes; buy an existing transmitter, open it up and study it.

I would imagine a transmission is triggered by having the push-button close a circuit, allowing a current to flow. This could be replicated in your current circuit by replacing the LED with a transistor switching circuit, affecting the current across the push-button switch.

It would be much less tedious to use an existing transmitter/relay set than to try and implement your own